# SDL2 No Console Output on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, stdout, sdl-2

I've tried just about everything I can think of. I just cannot get SDL2 to output anything to the console. Both Windows PowerShell and Command Prompt show no output. There's also no stdout.txt file. cout, cerr, SDL_Log("..."), none work.

```
#define NO_STDIO_REDIRECT
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** args){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Log("Hello World");


    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
message(STATUS "Print Test, CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: " ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(testproject)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH cmake/FindSDL2.cmake)
#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(testproject ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(testproject src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testproject ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Using GCC 4.8.3 (MinGW i686 Win-Builds 1.5)

Comment: [Does this help?](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=30116#30116)

Comment: Added this after add_executable(testproject src/main.cpp) : set_target_properties(testproject PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE FALSE)  and still no output.

Comment: Even from cout?

Comment: Which [`SUBSYSTEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) are you using?  `CONSOLE`?  `WINDOWS`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it's still relevant to you but have you tried the answer in [No stdout.txt with SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838840/no-stdout-txt-with-sdl/20857859#20857859)?

I used SDL 2 from MSYS2/MinGW-w64 where `pkg-config` set the `-mwindows` flag, which caused discarding of `stdout`/`stderr` when run from command prompt (but not with MSYS2 itself). Leaving out the `-mwindows` flag helped.